# Adding another table named posts that contains the user_id of Sentinel Cartalyst

Tags: php, cartalyst-sentinel

I am using Sentinel for authentication for my grading system project with added features like social networking system and advance authentication system, my problem is:

```
$post = new Post;

$post->title=$request->title; 
$post->body=$request->body; 
$post->user_id = auth()->user()->id; //need to convert into a cartalyst way
$post->save();
```

I want the id of the user table to be saved on the `user_id` of the posts table.

Answer (score 0):

Make a relation in Model then Use attach() function for attaching user to post for more info check Laravel Docs [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships]